# Summing Amplifier Zero Input Current/Voltage?

Tags: amplifier

I have 2 questions related to a summing amplifier:

1. Why is the voltage at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?
2. Why is the current at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the voltage at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?

Any opamp with negative feedback tries to keep its two inputs at the same voltage. Therefore, if the noninverting input is tied to ground, the action of the opamp is to keep the inverting input at ground, too.

> Why is the current at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?

An ideal opamp has infinite input resistance.

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you are using an inverting op amp with several resistors connected to the inverting terminal, the non-inverting terminal connected to ground, and a feedback resistor from the output to the inverting terminal?

In that case, the output of the amplifier will drive the feedback resistor to whatever voltage necessary to (ideally) drive the non-inverting terminal to zero volts.  (Since an ideal op-amp has infinite gain.)  So it's a feedback control system that keeps the non-inverting terminal at zero volts.

The input structure of an op-amp is a high impedance differential pair.  Ideally, it has infinite input impedance, so no current flows into either input of an op-amp.  In practice, there is leakage current and possibly bias current, but those are usually negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, for the moment, that we're talking about real amplifiers. Then both of your questions are not (quite) based on accurate assumptions. Let's start with the second:

> 2.Why is the current at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?

Well, it's not. If you look at the data sheet for an op amp you'll find a number called bias current. This is the current you're talking about, and it's not zero. It can be very small, though. Back in the early days of solid-state opamps, bias currents in the microamp region were common. Nowadays, you can get picoamp units cheaply. But, for perspective, let's say that you're using 1 k  resistors in a circuit that is working at 1 volt. Then the resistor current is about 1 milliamp. If the bias current is 10 nanoanps, this is 100,000 times less than the resistor current, and a bias current of 10 picoamps is 100,000,000 times less. So, even though the input current is not really zero, it is so small in comparison with the resistor currents as not to affect the circuit operation noticeably. An error of 1 part in 100,000 is .001 per cent, and resistors are usually held to a tolerance of +/- 1 per cent.

> 1.Why is the voltage at the inverting terminal of the input equal to zero?

Again, it's not. But let's say (again) than we're working at 1 volt levels. A regular op amp will have a DC gain of roughly 1,000,000. Then to get a 1 volt output, the inputs have to have a voltage difference of 1 microvolt. This is not zero, but it is so small that ignoring it won't cause errors that are not swamped by other sources of uncertainty.

So why does the theory you're learning start from obviously wrong assumptions? Because it simplifies the calculations and lets you see the general principles involved. If you later decide to go for the full monty and do a comprehensive analysis, that's fine too, but the results will be different by such a small amount that it's generally not worth the bother.